# ASP.NET Core MVC/WEB API with self-referencing type does not return json array

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

Hello WEB API developers!

I have problems when I try to return array object with my WEB API in MVC6.

On the debug controller, I obtain two or more objects but the result only sends a response with one object. I don't know what more to do for resolve this problem. Please help me!

My controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Maquina> Get()
    {
        var maquinas = _cobraAppContext.Maquina
            .Include(m => m.IdMarcaMotorNavigation)
            .Include(m => m.IdModeloNavigation)
            .ToList();
        return maquinas;//Two or more object obtains :(
    }
```

Response with only 1 object, but my controller debug show me more than one:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "M1",
    "idModelo": 3,
    "serie": "123456",
    "idMarcaMotor": 3,
    "serieMotor": "123456789",
    "descripcion": "ejemplo 123",
    "fechaCreacion": "2016-12-06T08:30:51.307",
    "idMarcaMotorNavigation": {
      "id": 3,
      "nombre": "DAEWO",
      "descripcion": "DAEWO",
      "fechaCreacion": "2016-11-29T15:17:33.223",
      "maquina": []
    }
  }
]
```

[image: Postman]

[image: Controller debug]

[image]

Comment: How are you invoking this api end point?

Comment: Do a get request with postman or something

Comment: The issue may be on the client side. If you can update your question with how you are trying to access this api, that will be helpful.

Comment: I've added the picture. I obtain the same response on postman, angularjs app and google chrome explorer.

Comment: Try again the solution that I updated

Comment: expand the maquinas object

Comment: @user2911678  I updated my answer, test for kindness.

Comment: ok @raphaelheitor let me check

Comment: i think @raphaelheitor is right. i suspect there is a cicrular reference in the second `Maquina` object

Comment: @user2911678: Can you see what is the value of s when you serialize your results object? var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(maquinas);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try another aproach(in Configuration method, Startup.cs):

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Comment: So I think it's circular reference.

Comment: @raphaelheitor circular reference will not return but rather throw an exception

Comment: @Alex are you sure about that? See here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4160

Comment: you may be right, the second object in the `maquinas` object might have a circular reference in the MarcaMotorNavigation

Comment: thank you @raphaelheitor.  what is exactly the problem?

Comment: @user2911678 Circular Reference. MotorNavigation have a object of Maquina type.  (looping reference)

Comment: @raphaelheitor, do I have something wrong or bad design?

Comment: @user2911678, You really need to assess if it is necessary. maquina have Motor object, which in turn has maquina as well. Perhaps for your design, it is not necessary for Motor to have the maquina object.

Answer (score -2):

Change your method signature to `IHttpActionResult` and your controller to `ApiController` method like this:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var maquinas = _cobraAppContext.Maquina
            .Include(m => m.IdMarcaMotorNavigation)
            .Include(m => m.IdModeloNavigation)
            .ToList();
        return Ok(maquinas);//Two or more object obtains :(
    }
```

Comment: this is web api

Comment: so what ?? I know it is a web Api. I don't understand you point

Comment: Web api will serialize the ienumerable

Comment: the problem in his solution is that IEnumerable uses delay execution, which means it get one entity at a time. Because of that he gets one object at a time.

Comment: try change .ToList() to .AsQueryable()

Comment: @Nadeem, the same problem :(

Comment: man try to change Controller to ApiController. Man noway, I have made the project as you do, and it works

Comment: thank you for your help @NadeemKhoury but I have all my controller like a ApiController.